# How can I let ProjectE's Matter Pickaxes mine other kinds of blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I can't help but notice that there seems to be some inconsistencies with what a 'Matter' Pickaxe in ProjectE can and cannot 'right-click-mine' between various Minecraft modpacks.

So that made me wonder; Is there something in the configuration files that would allow me to add blocks that the pickaxes can 'right-click-mine'? Like, say, allow me to mine a cluster of glowstone with a right click? Or mine ores from the NetherOres mod? I can't seem to find the setting anywhere, but something must be causing the inconsistencies.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it has to do with ore dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet was taken from the [Project E source code](https://github.com/sinkillerj/ProjectE) (utils/ItemHelper):

```
public static boolean isOre(Block block, int meta)
{
    if (block == Blocks.lit_redstone_ore)
    {
        return true;
    }
    String oreDictName = getOreDictionaryName(new ItemStack(block, 1, meta));
    return oreDictName.startsWith("ore") || oreDictName.startsWith("denseore");
}
```

This seems to indicate that Project E uses the Forge Ore Dictionary to determine if something is an ore.

Other than asking the developers of a mod to add their ores to the dictionary, there isn't much you can do. If you want to add vanilla blocks to this dictionary, you will have to create a Forge mod yourself.